# Получить первый знак строки jquery

Tags: jquery

Есть

```
<input id="pos_price" type="text" value="+20.25" />
valueField = parseInt(jQuery("input[id^='pos']").val());
```

таким макаром я получу все значение, а мне нужно только первый знак т.е. "+"

Как мне его получить?

Answer (score 2):

```
valueField = $("#pos_price").val().substr(0,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
valueField = jQuery('#pos_price').val()[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = "+20.25";
        var b;
        for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            if(i==0){
                b = a[i];
                break
            }
        }
        console.log(b);
```

Можно еще проще

```
var a = "+20.35";
        var b = a[0];

        console.log(b);
```